# Grouping two dates as one in Oracle-SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, count, group-by

I have a table 'task' with three relevant fields: date_created, date_updated, and is_closed.

I have a simple query that counts the number of tasks created:

```
SELECT task.date_created, count(task.is_closed)
FROM task
GROUP BY task.date_created
ORDER BY task.date_created
```

What I'd like is to also have the number of tasks closed per day. For our purposes, a task's final updated date is when is_closed='true'

So, the final table should look like

```
date      opened  closed
04/01/13  8       6
04/02/13  9       5
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a `WHERE task.is_closed=1` (assuming `is_closed` is of type `BIT`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` statement with your `COUNT`:

```
SELECT task.date_created, 
    count(1) opened, 
    count(case when is_closed = 'true' then 1 end) closed
FROM task
GROUP BY task.date_created
ORDER BY task.date_created
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/13bfa/1)

Given your comments, here is an approach using a couple `Common Table Expressions`:

```
WITH OPENED AS (
    SELECT date_created, count(1) opened
    FROM task
    GROUP BY date_created
  ) ,
CLOSED AS (
    SELECT date_updated, count(1) closed
    FROM task
    WHERE is_closed = 'true'
    GROUP BY date_updated
  )
SELECT D.YourDateField, o.opened, c.closed
FROM YourDateTable D
    LEFT JOIN Opened O ON D.YourDateField = O.Date_Created
    LEFT JOIN CLosed C ON D.YourDateField = C.Date_Created
```

As Gordon points out, a `FULL OUTER JOIN` would also work.  I just prefer using a dates table to seed from.  Create the table once, and use it wherever you may need to.

Comment: that seems to be a step in the right direction, but not all tasks are closed on the same day they are opened, hence the date_updated field.

Comment: I included a SQL Fiddle Demo for your review.  Didn't originally see anything in your post about different date fields, but it sounds like you'll need to use a subquery to return your desired results.

Comment: @MattMcD -- here is an updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/01bd7/1 -- very similar to Gordon's post above.  Use subqueries and if needed, a full outer join.  Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this as two subqueries.  Here is one approach, using `full outer join`:

```
select coalesce(a.date_created, c.date_updated) as thedate,
       coalesce(a.opened, 0) as opened,
       coalesce(c.closed, 0) as closed
from (select date_created, count(*) as opened
      from task
      group by date_created
     ) a full outer join
     (select date_updated, count(*) as closed
      from task
      where is_closed = 1  -- or whatever the value is
      group by date_updated
     ) c
     on a.date_created = c.date_updated
```

The `full outer join` guarantees that all dates are present, even when you have only closes or opens.